# Make colour change depending on time

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, color

I'm making a Flash game (ActionScript 3) and for dynamics I'd like to make the background change colour depending on the clients' time of day.

I have a rough idea on how I want to do this,

At sunrise, I want the background to be yellow-orange
In the middle of the day, I want the background to be cyan/clear sky colour
At sunset, a reddish-orange
During the night, a navy blue.

I will be using [this](http://www.smithmediafusion.com/blog/?p=377) method to change the colour of the symbol, which is at default a dark grey colour. (unless someone points out a better way to do this). This means I have access to the red, blue and green components of the background.

On implementing the system itself;
I suppose I could simply get the client time and do

```
if (hour > 9) and (hour < 18)
{
    colour = SKY_BLUE
}
```

and similar for the other times of day, but I'd like it to tween slowly between colours as time progresses. For example, if 6AM is yellow-orange and 9AM is blue, 7:30AM would be yellow moving towards blue. I have a feeling I need to come up with an algorithm to link time to the RGB components of the colour, but I've always been terrible at maths and I can't think of how to do this, so that's why I'm asking.

Please tell me how I would do this, both concept outlining and sample code, or even just tips are welcome. :)

Comment: Look up linear interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Reference Link for Date Time Functions
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html

Using the getHours() & getMinutes function you can decide the change in the color.

The Color Transform code which you have mentioned is pretty good to carry the color operation.